# Selenium- BS4 : Facing issue in scraping webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the company info of all the companies from the below given URL and view their job details
URL : http://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/Chandra Sekhar/Desktop/chrome-driver/chromedriver.exe")
titles=[]
driver.get("http://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'listing-links'}):
    info=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'userInfo'})
    print(info.text)
    titles.append(info.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Company info':titles})
    df['Price'] = df['Price'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))
    df.to_csv('products1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099036/issue-on-web-scraping/59100395#59100395

Comment: @ajayai What is the issue? Which line?? Error stack trace???

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη thanks for your concern. i have checked your csv file in that format only i need the output file. i am new to web scraping please share me the code to understand it better way. thanks @ αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: i already checked the file. please write the code in the Answer section

Comment: @ajayai check my answer below

Comment: ahmed american thanks for sharing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following `url`:

https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page=&listings_per_page=&view=list

Here's two parameter which you will edit `page=` and `listings_per_page=`:

Currently the website do have `37091` Jobs.

After my testing, I do see that `listings_per_page` is limited by `1000` per one page.

Example: https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page=1&listings_per_page=1000&view=list

So you will need to loop from `page=1` to `page=38` and set `listings_per_page=1000`

Which means `1000` result per page * `38` page = `38000`

**After that**:

You will collect all links and pass it to `list` with condition to remove duplicates in case if you worry about `sort`. Otherwise just pass it to `set` which doesn't accept duplicates but it's don't care about `sort`. Then you can parse each `url` in `list` or `set` to collect the information.

By The Way, I'll loop over `371` page and each page include 100 items so i will get `37100` `url` **(or less if the last page have little than 100 url)** and remove the duplicates from, then parse:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

links = []
try:
    for item in range(1, 372):
        print(f"Extraction Page# {item}")
        r = requests.get(
            f"https://desiopt.com/search-results-jobs/?action=search&page={item}&listings_per_page=100&view=list")
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for item in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'captions-field'}):
                for a in item.findAll('a'):
                    a = a.get('href')
                    if a not in links:
                        links.append(a)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Good Bye!")
    exit()

data = []
try:
    for link in links:
        r = requests.get(link)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'compProfileInfo'}):
                a = [a.text.strip() for a in item.findAll('span')]
                if a[6] == '':
                    a[6] = 'N/A'
                data.append(a[0:7:2])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Good Bye!")
    exit()

while True:
    try:
        with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(['Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Website'])
            writer.writerows(data)
            print("Operation Completed")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please Close The File")
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Good Bye")
        exit()
    break
```

Result Can Be Viewed Here:
[Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a7d3e60e56bbea29135eda11a9d78805/output.csv)

> The output is 1885 Rows because I've let the script to remove duplicated `links` for companies before i parsed.

Run Code Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/desioptcom)

Comment: @ahmed american when i am trying to execute the code i am getting the following error.     ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='desiopt.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search-results-jobs/?action=search&page=1&listings_per_page=100&view=list (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f428e7a5a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

Comment: @ajayai the website changed the design and require you to login first so you need to create account and make a post request